# Is the H-measure a strictly proper or a proper scoring rule?

Tags: scoring-rules, h-measure

The H-measure was proposed by Dr Hand in his article [Measuring classifier performance: a coherent alternative to the area under the ROC curve (2009)](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10994-009-5119-5), as a replacement for AUC-ROC. I haven't been able to find an article anywhere about the strictly proper/proper property of this measure.

Is the H-measure a strictly proper or a proper scoring rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is actually [a 2022/23 follow-up paper by Hand and Anagnostopoulos](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11634-021-00490-3), in which they answer this question (among others).

> As such it is not really meaningful to ask whether a *classification* performance measure itself is strictly proper or not, but it *is* meaningful to ask whether the probability scoring rule on which it is based is strictly proper. **For the H-measure, [...] the loss measure is strictly proper.**

(Emphasis mine.)