# Which metric to use to evaluate highly imbalance classification model performance

Tags: unbalanced-classes, accuracy, model-comparison

I have to do classification model to predict the possibilities of person getting cancer based on certain attributes. The data is highly imbalanced. As per client requirement I have to report model performance based on any one of these 4 metrics

```
AUC_Weighted
normalized root mean square
log loss
Accuracy
```

Can you suggest me which one should I use?

Comment: It's very unlikely that a single metric will have a one-to-one correspondence with the classification error from your model. Why not report them all?

Answer (score 2):

You should use proper [scoring-rules](/questions/tagged/scoring-rules) for probabilistic predictions. Take a look at the [tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info) for more information.

Log loss is a proper scoring rule. I personally would use this. The mean squared error between probabilistic predictions and the actual is the Brier score, which is also a proper scoring rule, so this would also be a possibility. As a matter of fact, [both scoring rules are actually *strictly* proper](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/477479/1352). Our thread [Why is LogLoss preferred over other proper scoring rules?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/274088/1352) compares the two.

Taking the root of the MSE will not have an impact on its properness. With normalization, it depends on how you want to normalize.

The AUC, as a scoring rule, is [problematic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/339919/1352).

[Accuracy is an improper scoring rule. More precisely, it's not a scoring rule at all.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/359909/1352) Don't use it. See also [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)

My personal favorite would be the log loss, with the Brier score as a close second, for reasons given in [the thread linked above](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/274088/1352).

Comment: In your opinion, why did not the client also suggest the AIC and the BIC as model selection tools ?

Comment: @CamilleGontier: I don't know. But information criteria are *model selection* tools, as you write, while the KPIs above are *prediction quality* KPIs. The client may simply be more interested in holdout prediction performance.