# How to evaluate multi-class classifier on probability prediction task?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, auc, multi-class, calibration

I have a balanced dataset where each object (song) has one of the four target class labels (mood of a song). Example:

| ID | feature1 | feture2 | feature3 | target_class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.5 | 0.11 | 125 | upbeat |
| 1 | 0.23 | 0.75 | 136 | sad |

Dataset has some outliers which I decided not to remove since they aren't measurement errors. I want to predict probability of each object belonging to each of the four classes, for example:

| ID | upbeat | sad | energetic | relaxing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.75 | 0.13 | 0.5 | 0.7 |
| 1 | 0.2 | 0.65 | 0.03 | 0.12 |

I'm planning to use this classifier on the unknown data in order to build a music database. The reason why I want to predict probabilities is so that instead of choosing one of the four moods user will be able to choose *in between* of the four moods when searching for music in the database.

So I have a couple of questions:

1. How do I evaluate classifier in this case? I'm thinking LogLoss, ROC-AUC, Brier score and ECE. But I've read that ROC-AUC isn't a good metric when it comes to multiclass problem.While LogLoss is more informative in case of imbalanced dataset.
2. Is it correct to optimize LogLoss in order to tune hyperparameters?

Comment: Your question is too broad. I think it would help if you provided more info on what you are trying to achieve in your use case. In general there is no best model w.r.t. all evaluation metrics and there is no best metric which should be always used.

Comment: @picky_porpoise thank you! I edited my question in order to explain my use case, hope it narrows it down a bit.

Comment: Who told you that log loss is bad in multiclass settings?

Comment: @Dave I can't find the source and I formulated it wrong. I've read that it's more informative in case of imbalanced dataset

Comment: What you’ve maybe read is that classification accuracy becomes problematic in the case of imbalance. [There are valid arguments that classification accuracy is problematic in the balanced setting, too. This link argues for so-called (strictly) proper scoring rules, of which log loss and Brier score are two examples.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/247274)

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect you have read is that classification accuracy becomes problematic in the case of imbalance. There are valid arguments that classification accuracy is problematic in the balanced setting, too. [This link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/247274) argues for so-called (strictly) proper scoring rules, whether the classes are imbalanced or not, of which log loss and Brier score are two examples. [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/603663/247274) question and the accepted answer discuss how other threshold-based metrics are problematic, whether there is balance or imbalance. Strictly proper scoring rules evaluate the raw probability predictions of models and can be thought of as seeking out the true (conditional) probability values.

Both log loss and Broer score can be normalized $R^2$-style as McFadden’s and Efron’s [pseudo $R^2$](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-pseudo-r-squareds/), respectively, which may be easier to interpret as improvement over a simple benchmark.

Much of the discussion about log loss and Brier score is about the binary setting, [but both log loss and Brier score are strictly proper in the multi-class setting, too](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/493940/247274). Either if these, perhaps normalized to a pseudo $R^2$, are likely to work well for you.

(In `Keras` lingo, log loss is categorical cross-entropy.)